# Change background color of all charts beside the one hovered

Tags: reactjs, chart.js, chartjs-2.6.0

I want to change reg color of all the bar's except the one user hovers on. like in the pic below the chart i hovered on is light blue but i want to make every other bar light blue and keep the one as dark blue which is hovered.

```
const data = 
  {
    labels: label,
    datasets:[
      {
        label:'',
        data: values,
        backgroundColor: '#1690ca',
        hoverBackgroundColor: '#d0e9f4'
      }
    ]
  }
```

[image]

Comment: If I understand you correctly, just switch backgroundColor and hoverBackgroundColor?

Comment: Kind of. But i want to change every other bar's color and just not change the color of the bar i hovered on.

Comment: Ah I see, I dont think that that's possible because you would have to insert your custom css to enable something like this with :hover tags, but since the charts are rendered as canvas, you cannot access it easily with css.

Comment: @Domino987 can i get some order of the bar i hovered on onHover function?
Then i can do a function to change the color or that specific bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, you could do it like this:

```
 const BarChart = ({values}) => {

  [data, setData] = useState([]);
  [hovering, setHovering] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    setData({
      labels: label,
      datasets:values.map((value, index) => ({
        label:'',
        data: value,
        backgroundColor: index === hovering ? '#1690ca' :  '#d0e9f4',
        hoverBackgroundColor: index === hovering ? '#d0e9f4' :  '#1690ca',
      }))
    });
  },[hovering, values]);

<Bar
  data={data}
  width={100}
  height={50}
  options={{ onHover: (event,elements) => setHovering(elements[0]._index) }}
/>
}
```

This will update your data to set the colors of the currently hovered element as you mentioned within your question. You probably have to change it to match your data/setup, but this works for my setup.

Hope this helps. Happy coding.

Comment: Awesome thanks for the answer. the only thing i was missing out was the elements param in onHover function. Thanks